# Turn items from a string in a list

Tags: python, string, file

When I read in a .txt file like this:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
 content = f.readlines()
 for row in content:
  print(row)
```

I have the following input:

```
['k'], ['m']
```

I would like to transform this into:

```
[k, m]
```

So therefore I try

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
 content = f.readlines()
 for row in content:
  items = items.replace('\'', '') for item in items
  row_analyze = ','.join(items)
```

This however gives me:

```
[,,k,,],,,[,,m,,],
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What data really contains in the file ?

Comment: `items = items.replace('\'', '') for item in items` does not make sense. did you mean `items = [item.replace('\'', '') for item in row]`?

Comment: Going back further, where did the `'sample.txt'` come from? Probably you can avoid this intermediate file or store it properly as a python object via the `pickle` or `json` module

Answer (score 0):

The sting `['k'], ['m']`, actually represents a tuple of lists, which you can simply convert it to a python tuple object using `ast.literal_eval()` function, then chain the lists using `itertools.chain()` function:

```
In [1]: s = "['k'], ['m']"

In [2]: import ast

In [3]: ast.literal_eval(s)
Out[3]: (['k'], ['m'])

In [4]: from itertools import chain

In [6]: list(chain.from_iterable(ast.literal_eval(s)))
Out[6]: ['k', 'm']
```

Comment: Note that OP seems to want output like `[k, m]`, without `'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `row` is the string `"['k'], ['m']"`. If you want to transform this to `"[k, m]"`, some simple `replace` statements should suffice. First, remove the `'`, but then, instead of `join`ing the characters in the string with `,`, replace those remaining `] ,[` with just `,`.

```
>>> row = "['k'], ['m']"
>>> row.replace("'", '')
'[k], [m]'
>>> row.replace("'", "").replace("], [", ", ")
'[k, m]'
```